# "message": "Path `user` is required.",

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

req.body.user = req.user._id , user is not stored in db and response coming is "message": **"Path `user` is required.",**

I have tried to log thr req.body , and their user is coming but don't know why it is not storing in the database

`//routes router.route('/admin/newproducts').post(isUserAuthenticated,authroziedRole('admin'),newProducts);` .

```
//productController ->newproducts
const newProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 
     const product = { ...req.body, user: req.user._id }; 
  console.log('new product', JSON.stringify(product, null, 2))
   product = await Product.create(req.body);
  return res.status(200).json({
    product,
  });
});

//auth.js
const AsyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorHandler");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/users");

// check if user is authenticate or not

const isUserAuthenticated = AsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  console.log(token);

  if (!token) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Login First To view this content", 401));
  }
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SCERET);
  // console.log(decoded);
  req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
  next();
});

const authroziedRole = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return next(
        new ErrorHandler(
          `${req.user.role} is not allowed to access this resource`
        )
      );
    }
    next();
  };
};

module.exports = { isUserAuthenticated, authroziedRole };


// db model
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Enter Product Name"],
      maxLength: [200, "Product Name cannot exceed 200 characters"],
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "Please Enter Product Price"],
      maxLength: [5, "Product Price cannot exceed 5 characters"],
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Enter Product Description"],
      maxLength: [3200, "Product Description cannot exceed 200 characters"],
    },
    ratings: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    images: [
      {
        public_id: [
          {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
        ],
        url: [
          {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Enter Product Category"],
      enum: {
        values: [
          "Electronics",
          "Cameras",
          "Laptops",
          "Accessories",
          "Headphones",
          "Food",
          "Books",
          "Sports",
          "Outdoor",
          "Home",
        ],
        message: "Please select correct category",
      },
    },
    seller: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please Enter Product Seller"],
    },
    stock: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "Please Enter Product Stocks"],
    },
    numOfReviews: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    reviews: [
      {
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
          required: true,
        },
        ratings: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        comment: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Product;

//json file for api testing
[
  {
    "name": "2 Ultra 128GB SDXC UHS-I Memory Card up to 80MB/s",
    "price": 45.89,
    "description":
      "Ultra-fast cards (2) to take better pictures and Full HD videos (1) with your compact to mid-range point-and-shoot",
    "ratings": 4.5,
    "images": [
      {
        "public_id": "shopit/demo/nkkjkta63uiazppzkmjf",
        "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/udemy-courses/image/upload/v1698577488/shopit/demo/nkkjkta63uiazppzkmjf.jpg"
      },
      {
       "public_id": "shopit/demo/hz1iwdqzrvxtfxincvju",
        "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/udemy-courses/image/upload/v1698577488/shopit/demo/hz1iwdqzrvxtfxincvju.jpg"
      },
      {
        "public_id": "shopit/demo/oc2dvvkxyxukc13y9pjv",
        "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/udemy-courses/image/upload/v1698577488/shopit/demo/oc2dvvkxyxukc13y9pjv.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "category": "Electronics",
    "seller": "Amazon",
    "stock": 50,
    "noOfReviews": 32,
    "reviews": []
  }
]
//Error Message
{
  "message": "Path `user` is required.",
  "error": {
    "errors": {
      "user": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `user` is required.",
        "properties": {
          "message": "Path `user` is required.",
          "type": "required",
          "path": "user"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "user"
      }
    },
    "_message": "Product validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Product validation failed: user: Path `user` is required."
  },
  "stack": "ValidationError: Product validation failed: user: Path `user` is required.\n    at Document.invalidate (D:\\UrbanHub\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:3187:32)\n    at D:\\UrbanHub\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:2980:17\n    at D:\\UrbanHub\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schemaType.js:1368:9\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)"
}
//log req.body
new product {
  "0": {
    "name": "2 Ultra 128GB SDXC UHS-I Memory Card up to 80MB/s",
    "price": 45.89,
    "description": "Ultra-fast cards (2) to take better pictures and Full HD videos (1) with your compact to mid-range point-and-shoot",
    "ratings": 4.5,
    "images": [
      {
        "public_id": "shopit/demo/nkkjkta63uiazppzkmjf",
        "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/udemy-courses/image/upload/v1698577488/shopit/demo/nkkjkta63uiazppzkmjf.jpg"
      },
      {
        "public_id": "shopit/demo/hz1iwdqzrvxtfxincvju",
        "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/udemy-courses/image/upload/v1698577488/shopit/demo/hz1iwdqzrvxtfxincvju.jpg"
      },
      {
        "public_id": "shopit/demo/oc2dvvkxyxukc13y9pjv",
        "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/udemy-courses/image/upload/v1698577488/shopit/demo/oc2dvvkxyxukc13y9pjv.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "category": "Electronics",
    "seller": "Amazon",
    "stock": 50,
    "noOfReviews": 32,
    "reviews": []
  },
  "user": "65aeb82fcdf62bb6e528fb84"
}
```

by the way i am following MERN Stack Full Ecommerce Site - Using React, Redux, Node.js by ghulam abbas on udemy.

Comment: Instead of directly manipulating `req.body`, I'd create a new object... `const product = { ...req.body, user: req.user._id }`. Then log it to make sure it looks right... `console.log('new product', JSON.stringify(product, null, 2))`

Comment: How are you making the request? From the comments on the answer below, it sounds like you're not setting the request body correctly or you're missing `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: I have already added app use(express.json()) and the above approach I have used and still gets same error."message": "Please Enter Product Stocks,Please Enter Product Seller,Please Enter Product Category,Please Enter Product Description,Please Enter Product Price,Please Enter Product Name",.

Comment: When I log , I get the desired output on the terminal but get error on the response. You any look my model and json file which I have added in th e code.

Comment: Sounds like the error message in your question is no longer what you're seeing. Please [edit] your question with any code changes you've made and include the error messages **in full** and the result of any logging you've added

Comment: i have added your code and after that the error and the result which i am logging in the above code. Please check and update me.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to overwrite the request object.
Create a new object:

```
const productData = {...req.body};
console.log("USER_ID: ", req.user._id); // check if the user is not undefined
productData.user = req.user._id; 
const product = await Product.create(productData);
  return res.status(200).json({
    product,
  });
```

Your error is coming from MongoDB, it says that the user field is missing while writing to DB.

Better try this approach:

```
const productData = {...req.body};
    console.log("USER_ID: ", req.user._id); // check if the user is not undefined
    productData.user = req.user._id; 
    const newProduct = new Product(productData);
const product = await newProduct.save();

      return res.status(200).json({
        product
      });
```

Comment: "Model.create() no longer accepts a callback" this message is coming

Comment: Did you set a "," after "productData"? Like: Product.create(productData,); ? You shouldn't do that.

Comment: no i have notset "," , it shows validatorError. "message": "Please Enter Product Stocks,Please Enter Product Seller,Please Enter Product Category,Please Enter Product Description,Please Enter Product Price,Please Enter Product Name",

Comment: I updated my answer, try the approach i mentioned below my previous answer.

Comment: "message": "Please Enter Product Stocks,Please Enter Product Seller,Please Enter Product Category,Please Enter Product Description,Please Enter Product Price,Please Enter Product Name",. I have also added my model above . please check if it correct or there is something issue